# AWS Sqs Source Connector to Kafka

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, amazon-sqs, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to connect to AWS sqs Queue where my data is stored. I have the Aws.key and secret with me. I also have the SQS Source Connector which transfers data from SQS queue to my Kafka topic. I would like to know how to do that. **Do I need to work on the AWS console ? How to use the Source Connector to transfer the data ?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy your own infrastructure (doesn't require the console, no) running Kafka Connect, then install the SQS connector plugin and then HTTP POST the connector config to its REST API

Comment: Thanks. I found out the connector was running already. Sending data to queue was enough, data was forwarded automatically thereafter.